# Run MySQL Script in Travis

Tags: mysql, travis-ci

So, we have an empty database script that we need to run on travis before doing unit testing. It sets up the database schema and fills in a few fields. How can we do this? We have the MySQL being created correctly so far, just need to run the script.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, I configured my file .travis.yml

```
language: php
php:
  - '5.5'
  - '5.6'
service:
  - mysql
install:
  - composer install
before_install:
  - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS baladay;'  
  - mysql -u root --default-character-set=utf8 baladay < scripts/bd.sql
script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
```